# Can I change the name of the request object the session is stored in? Problem with two sessions clashing

Tags: javascript, express, session, passport.js

I have a problem with the session that passport sets up to work with the twitter api because I already have an active session on the same connection that regulates the relation between my client, my application server and a more general server that manages multiple applications. This existing session is set up on the general server and I don't have easy access to it. I could request changes to it, but I'd have to know what I'm asking first. When i try to set up a session on my connection using express,

```
app.use(session({ secret: 'blablabla'}));
```

it throws a "TypeError: req.session.touch is not a function" error indicating that this new session is trying to override the existing one. This breaks quite a few features on my site.

One way of fixing this, and this works, is setting up a separate connection just for the communication between twitter and my application server. This is a viable fallback, but there are several application specific reasons why this is not ideal for me.

What I'd like to do, however, is for this to work without having to add a new port to my server. One thought I had is that I could maybe change the name of the object from req.session to req.session2 and avoid clashes. This wouldn't work on the twitter session because twitter wouldn't know to look at req.session2, but is there a way to tell my application server and the general server it is communicating with to look for the session data in req.session2 instead of req.session? Or is there some other approach to this that I haven't even thought of?